# conda init powershell has no effect

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda3 on my Windows Laptop and tried to make the conda activate command available in powershell so that I can use the conda env in VS Code for a Jupyter Notebook. But the problem is this:

1. Added Conda to the Environment-PATH
2. I executed **conda init powershell** in the conda prompt and closed it afterwars
3. opened powershell and executed **set-executionpolicy remotesigned**
4. then i restarted the computer
5. eventhough it should be working at this point I still get the following message when executing **conda activate base** inside powershell:

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to
> use 'conda activate'. If using 'conda activate' from a batch script,
> change your invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'. To initialize
> your shell, run conda init <SHELL_NAME> Currently supported shells
> are:
>
> - bash
> - cmd.exe
> - fish
> - tcsh
> - xonsh
> - zsh
> - powershell
>
> See 'conda init --help' for more information and options. IMPORTANT:
> You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda
> init'.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that your powershell could execute `conda init` successfully.

> 2.I executed conda init powershell in the conda prompt and closed it afterwars

Normally this command will edit this account's powershell startup config file, which locates in `C:\Users\[YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`. Please make sure that the edited file include codes like this **in your personal folder**:

```
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

Sometimes the code page that powershell is using may cause jumbled characters **when your account name includes non-ascii characters**, resulting in editing the `profile.ps1` in the jumbled path. Just copy it into your real account path as shown above.