# conda init powershell giving "no actions taken"

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm trying to use miniconda in powershell on my Windows laptop, but `conda init powershell` seems not working.

Running `conda init powershell` gives:

```
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\condabin\conda.bat
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\condabin\activate.bat
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\condabin\deactivate.bat
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\Scripts\activate
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\Scripts\deactivate
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\xontrib\conda.xsh
no change     D:\Program Files\miniconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
No actions taken.
```

So it doesn't modify anything. I noticed that when it initializes for cmd, there is an extra line like:

```
no change     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

I guess it's trying to modify some settings for the shell, and I know it's necessary from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69471896/conda-init-powershell-has-no-effect), but I still wonder why it fails to do so for powershell.